# Changing C drive permissions from Ubuntu to Windows?

Tags: windows-8

I cannot access the C drive or launch apps that requires admin permission on my Windows 8, because I've changed C drive admin or user permission to full deny.

I've tried many methods but it didn't work. Can I do it from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

> So can i do it from ubuntu?

No. Permissions on Windows are not changeable from Ubuntu. If you have problems accessing a disc from within Windows you will have to fix this from within Windows.

2 quotes:

> Windows now contains some newer components like Junctions, Symbolic Links, and other NTFS system files that can cause major problems if they are mishandled, such as changing the permissions.

and

> If you've tried these suggestions and still can't sign in:
>
> If you have Windows 8.1, you'll need to reinstall Windows.

I am glad I am using Linux.